# What is the most reliable way to get a Windows 8/8.1 computer into Advanced Startup Options menu?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, safe-mode

I would like to know what the best way to get a computer running Windows 8 or 8.1 into the light blue Advanced Startup Options menu is.

Also list the ways to get into Safe Mode if different from the ways above.

If possible, account for the fact that *something is wrong* with the computer and they cannot log in. Also, while I realize that <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> is a good way to get into the menu, most computers nowadays are "too fast" to see it.

**My video drivers are broken, so it's kind of hard to open a command prompt. I'm not even sure if I am logged in or not.**

Comment: Please update your question with relevant information, such as in your comments.  Why in the world did you not include that up front?

Comment: I did. "If possible, account for the fact that something is wrong with the computer and they cannot log in"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How To Boot Into Safe Mode via CMD**

```
Safe Mode:
    bcdedit /set {default} safeboot minimal

Safe Mode with Networking:
    bcdedit /set {default} safeboot network

Safe Mode with Command Prompt:
    bcdedit /set {default} safeboot minimal
    bcdedit /set {default} safebootalternateshell yes
```

**Note**: This will set the default to *always be safe mode*, so to undo that:

```
bcdedit /deletevalue {default} safeboot
```

---

**How to Boot Into the Advanced Menu (8/8.1)**

This can be accomplished any of the following ways:

1. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Click Restart (almost as if you were restarting the normal way)
2. <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>, click "Change PC Settings" > Update & Recovery > Recovery > Advanced Startup > Restart Now
3. cmd: `shutdown /r /o /t 0`

Item 3 summarized:

> **/r** = This option will shut down and then restart the local computer or
>   the remote computer specified in /m.
>   **/o** = Use this shutdown switch to end the current Windows session and
>   open the Advanced Boot Options menu. This option must be used with /r.
>   The /o switch is new beginning in Windows 8.

**Edit**

Since you changed your parameters:

1. Try to recall if you had auto login on or off.
2. Plug in head phones/speakers
3. Boot your computer
4. Wait a while
5. If auto log-in, skip this step.  Else: login - listen for the audible queues and wait a bit.
6. Type <kbd>WIN + R</kbd>
7. Very carfully type one of the desired commands.
8. Hit ENTER, wait, and hope it works.

Otherwise, just get a linux disc and an external drive (or use GDrive/dropbox/whatever) to back up important data.  Then reformat.

Comment: My video drivers are broken, so it's kind of hard to open a command prompt. I'm not even sure if I am logged in or not.

Comment: @JeffreyLin - See my edit to try to account for that.  Next time, include all relevant information up front.  Your initial question seemed strictly aimed to learn about options.

Comment: Sorry about that. I think that I had turned off Windows sounds before. I will try waiting a while longer during each step to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

On the left side in PC settings, click/tap on Update & Recovery.

[image]

On the left side in Update & Recovery, click/tap on Recovery, click/tap on the Restart now button under the Advanced startup section on the right side.

When your PC restarts, you will now see the Advanced Startup Options at boot.

Comment: My drivers are broken so this pretty hard to do.

Comment: this would have been useful information in the original question. Regardless of how fast your computer boots, good old fashioned F8 should work with no problem, it may take a few tries, but it still works that way.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: kill the power 3 times before it completely boots.

Long answer:
Sorry if I am kind of late into this conversation. Just wanted to tell someone having a same problem as I could not find it somewhere else. (Maybe I didn't try hard enough)

I was having a similar problem after trying to install a windows theme.
It got pretty messed up as i could not determine what was happening.
Exactly what I saw on my screen includes, black flickering screen like a crt, 1 or 2 icons flashing in for half a second at the lower left corner, and mouse cursor jumping to the middle of the screen every few seconds. Attempt to login into windows didn't work. Managed to boot into a windows 8.1 usb and repair but didn't solve the issue.

Searched the internet until i reread this sentence in a different way.

"Advanced Startup Option Menu will be displayed after 3 failed attempts to load Windows automatically"

Kill the power before it boots completely, 3 times, then safe boot. It worked!