# Surefire safe mode for Windows 8.x?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, safe-mode

I'm having a devil of a time trying to get Windows 8.x into `safe mode`.  From what I've read it seems nigh impossible to do this without doing a jig and catching a leprechaun first.

The shift-(mash)F8 just doesn't do the trick.  I've tried this on about 10 computers so far ranging from various 8 and 8.1 editions with no joy.

Is there a sure fire mechanism to trigger `safe mode` now?  I'm even open to the idea of some CD/ISO that is set up to trigger this by modifying the boot.ini or such if you know of a tool like this.  There are way too many situations where I'm needing `safe mode` to keep going on like this otherwise.

Comment: There are two ways to get into Windows 8 safe mode both are extremely easy. The first is the `Advanced Startup Options Menu` boot options enabled by selecting that option in `msconfig` the other is to force Windows 8 to fail durin the loading process 3 times. The reason the `Advanced Startup Option Menu` must be used because of the extremely fast boot times allowed by UEFI partitions.  The F8 method was actually removed since it wouldn't have been possible to hit within the 1-2 seconds it actually would have been valid.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/701693/what-is-the-most-reliable-way-to-get-a-windows-8-8-1-computer-into-advanced-star?rq=1 and http://superuser.com/questions/476187/how-do-i-boot-windows-8-into-safe-mode

Comment: The key here for me is to get into `safe mode` when there is one cannot get into windows to run `msconfig`.  That is about the case 1/4 - 1/2 the time for me, so thanks.  Let me give that a go.

Comment: Hence the reason I mention the fact the `Advanced Startup Option Menu` will be displayed after 3 failed attempts to load Windows automatically.

Comment: On that `Advanced Startup Option Menu`, what is the "best" way to make bootup fail. I hate to just power it off during boot (coming from a *nix background it makes me queasy), but that's the only thing I can think of off the top here.

Comment: @ylluminate - I don't understand the question.  If Windows is crashing because of a driver, after 3 failed attempts, it will offer that menu.  Are you simply trying to replicate 3 failed attempts?  The reset button works wonders for that.

Comment: LOL, trying to not destroy the filesystem by hard resets.  But that sounds as though it may be the only option.  Thanks.

Comment: Still not clear what your trying to do.  Sounds like Windows 8 boots